# Identify Internal Request Nginx + NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have an NodeJS API using Express Framework.

I use Nginx for Load Balancing betwween my NodeJS instances. I use PM2 to spawn NodeJS Instances.

I identified in the log that Ngnix makes some "dummy/internal" requests, probably to identify if the instance is on (heartbeat requests could be the appropriate name for this requests).

My question is: Which is the right method to identifiy these "dummy/internal" requests on my API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that nginx only uses passive health checks for upstream servers. In other words – because all HTTP requests are assumed to result in a response, nginx says "If I send this server a bunch of requests and don't get responses for them, I'll consider the server to be unhealthy".

Can you share some access logs of the requests you're seeing?

As far as I know, nginx does not send any requests to upstream servers that are not ultimately initiated by a client.

Comment: http:
    clientHost:191.X.X.X
    contentType:application/json
    json:
    level:info
    logId:e07230e902f18c7fb8862358ef256555
timestamp:2017-08-08T13:33:59.856Z
request:
ip:::ffff:127.0.0.1
method:GET
originalUrl:/
requestId:e07230e902f18c7fb8862358ef256555
headers:
accept:*/*
connection:upgrade
host:191.X.X.X
user-agent:curl/7.17.1 (mips-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.17.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8i zlib/1.2.3
x-request-id:e07230e902f18c7fb8862358ef256555

Comment: The above log is one example request that seens to be initated automatically by nginx.

Comment: Why do you think this was initiated by nginx?

Comment: because is is a localhost request user-agent:curl/7.17.1 and i am not making any request on it.